# Retrieve a node value from xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to get the value of a node `<abc>` from xmldata column.

XML data looks like:

```
<data id="d4E8121C9636942F18AC77F3EECD13ABA">
    <d id="pDF21A1781B684FAD8D476BF14F78D52D">
        <abc>ABC</abc>
    </d> 
</data>
```

Here is the code:

```
using (var exampleSource = new ExampleDataSource())
{
    var xmlData = exampleSource.queue
        .Where(a => a.QueueID == queueID)
        .Select(a => a.XMLData)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    var messages = from m in xmlData 
                   select XElement.Parse("abc");
}
```

Comment: Why are you parsing a constant `"abc"`?  And what type is `XMLData`?

Comment: is xmlData an `XDocument`?

Comment: XMLData is a column name in Queue table of type nvarchar(max) .

Comment: I edited your question + title. This has nothing to do with Entity Framework. It's irrelevant where xmlData comes from, because you're just parsing a string in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said `XMLData` is a `string`, you need to parse this and then get the value of `abc` like so:

```
var abc = (string)XElement.Parse(xmlData).Descendants("abc").Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

`XElement.Parse()` is for turning a string into an XElement.

I think you simply want `xmlData.Descendents("d").Descendents("abc")`.